# Offset Margin-Left Percentages for Fluid Row in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Up to and including Twitter Bootstrap v2.0.4, there have been no CSS margin-left percentages when using the offset class in a row-fluid scenario. I have looked on SO and other sites for an answer but cannot find one.

Does anyone have this information that I can add to my bootstrap-responsive.css file?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Please transform that to a proper question that clearly states a problem and does not include a solution, then post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Use the self-answer feature instead, please.

Comment: The best thing to do is to ask a typical question and then (after the mandatory delay) give the answer. There is the possibility that your typical question might duplicate another -- into which it is merged -- so your answer can answer that as well. After another wait, you can accept your own answer too. For now, I suggest editing your "question" to include the actual question to which this is the answer, and then when you can add an answer, do that, removing it from the "question".

Comment: @AndrewLeach: is there a mandatory delay? I seem to be able to post a question and answer it all at once.

Comment: @Len Perhaps it's rep-dependent. There may be something in Meta about it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach there's something on the blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent one night with Excel and came up with the following CSS:

```
/* ---------- Start of bootstrap-responsive.css offset left-margin ---------- */
.row-fluid .offset12 {
margin-left: 105.524861871% !important;
*margin-left: 104.195074636958% !important;
}

.row-fluid .offset11 {
margin-left: 96.96132596% !important;
*margin-left: 95.7379217046809% !important;
}

.row-fluid .offset10 {
margin-left: 88.397790049% !important;
*margin-left: 87.2807687724043% !important;
}

.row-fluid .offset9 {
margin-left: 79.834254138% !important;
*margin-left: 78.8236158401277% !important;
}

.row-fluid .offset8 {
margin-left: 71.270718227% !important;
*margin-left: 70.3664629078511% !important;
}

.row-fluid .offset7 {
margin-left: 62.707182316% !important;
*margin-left: 61.9093099755745% !important;
}

.row-fluid .offset6 {
margin-left: 54.143646405% !important;
*margin-left: 53.4521570432979% !important;
}

.row-fluid .offset5 {
margin-left: 45.580110494% !important;
*margin-left: 44.9950041110213% !important;
}

.row-fluid .offset4 {
margin-left: 37.016574583% !important;
*margin-left: 36.5378511787447% !important;
}

.row-fluid .offset3 {
margin-left: 28.453038672% !important;
*margin-left: 28.0806982464681% !important;
}

.row-fluid .offset2 {
margin-left: 19.889502761% !important;
*margin-left: 19.6235453141915% !important;
}

.row-fluid .offset1 {
margin-left: 11.32596685% !important;
*margin-left: 11.1663923819149% !important;
}

/* ---------- End of bootstrap-responsive.css offset left-margin ---------- */
```

I inserted this into bootstrap-responsive.css, starting at line 370 (after the close of the style block for .row-fluid .span1

It solved my website issues. It was only tested in FF13. It may cause issues in other browsers.

I am pretty new to SO so I apologize if this was not the recommended method of posting info like this. Its all a work-in-progress.

Answer (score 5):

You may also need the original offset. It's better to add another code for offset to left.

I added a new class named offsetright and added this code to bootstrap.css:

```
.row-fluid .offsetright12 {
  margin-right: 104.25531914893617%;
  *margin-right: 104.14893617021275%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright12:last-child {
  margin-right: 102.12765957446808%;
  *margin-right: 102.02127659574467%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright11 {
  margin-right: 95.74468085106382%;
  *margin-right: 95.6382978723404%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright11:last-child {
  margin-right: 93.61702127659574%;
  *margin-right: 93.51063829787232%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright10 {
  margin-right: 87.23404255319149%;
  *margin-right: 87.12765957446807%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright10:last-child {
  margin-right: 85.1063829787234%;
  *margin-right: 84.99999999999999%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright9 {
  margin-right: 78.72340425531914%;
  *margin-right: 78.61702127659572%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright9:last-child {
  margin-right: 76.59574468085106%;
  *margin-right: 76.48936170212764%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright8 {
  margin-right: 70.2127659574468%;
  *margin-right: 70.10638297872339%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright8:last-child {
  margin-right: 68.08510638297872%;
  *margin-right: 67.9787234042553%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright7 {
  margin-right: 61.70212765957446%;
  *margin-right: 61.59574468085106%;
}

.row-fluid .offset7right:last-child {
  margin-right: 59.574468085106375%;
  *margin-right: 59.46808510638297%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright6 {
  margin-right: 53.191489361702125%;
  *margin-right: 53.085106382978715%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright6:last-child {
  margin-right: 51.063829787234035%;
  *margin-right: 50.95744680851063%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright5 {
  margin-right: 44.68085106382979%;
  *margin-right: 44.57446808510638%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright5:last-child {
  margin-right: 42.5531914893617%;
  *margin-right: 42.4468085106383%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright4 {
  margin-right: 36.170212765957444%;
  *margin-right: 36.06382978723405%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright4:last-child {
  margin-right: 34.04255319148936%;
  *margin-right: 33.93617021276596%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright3 {
  margin-right: 27.659574468085104%;
  *margin-right: 27.5531914893617%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright3:last-child {
  margin-right: 25.53191489361702%;
  *margin-right: 25.425531914893618%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright2 {
  margin-right: 19.148936170212764%;
  *margin-right: 19.04255319148936%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright2:last-child {
  margin-right: 17.02127659574468%;
  *margin-right: 16.914893617021278%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright1 {
  margin-right: 10.638297872340425%;
  *margin-right: 10.53191489361702%;
}

.row-fluid .offsetright1:last-child {
  margin-right: 8.51063829787234%;
  *margin-right: 8.404255319148938%;
}
```

Do the same for bootstrap-responsive.css:

```
.row-fluid .offsetright12 {
    margin-right: 105.12820512820512%;
    *margin-lerightft: 105.02182214948171%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright12:last-child {
    margin-right: 102.56410256410257%;
    *margin-right: 102.45771958537915%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright11 {
    margin-right: 96.58119658119658%;
    *margin-right: 96.47481360247316%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright11:last-child {
    margin-right: 94.01709401709402%;
    *margin-right: 93.91071103837061%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright10 {
    margin-right: 88.03418803418803%;
    *margin-right: 87.92780505546462%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright10:last-child {
    margin-right: 85.47008547008548%;
    *margin-right: 85.36370249136206%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright9 {
    margin-right: 79.48717948717949%;
    *margin-right: 79.38079650845607%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright9:last-child {
    margin-right: 76.92307692307693%;
    *margin-right: 76.81669394435352%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright8 {
    margin-right: 70.94017094017094%;
    *margin-right: 70.83378796144753%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright8:last-child {
    margin-right: 68.37606837606839%;
    *margin-right: 68.26968539734497%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright7 {
    margin-right: 62.393162393162385%;
    *margin-right: 62.28677941443899%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright7:last-child {
    margin-right: 59.82905982905982%;
    *margin-right: 59.72267685033642%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright6 {
    margin-right: 53.84615384615384%;
    *margin-right: 53.739770867430444%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright6:last-child {
    margin-right: 51.28205128205128%;
    *margin-right: 51.175668303327875%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright5 {
    margin-right: 45.299145299145295%;
    *margin-right: 45.1927623204219%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright5:last-child {
    margin-right: 42.73504273504273%;
    *margin-right: 42.62865975631933%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright4 {
    margin-right: 36.75213675213675%;
    *margin-right: 36.645753773413354%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright4:last-child {
    margin-right: 34.18803418803419%;
    *margin-right: 34.081651209310785%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright3 {
    margin-right: 28.205128205128204%;
    *margin-right: 28.0987452264048%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright3:last-child {
    margin-right: 25.641025641025642%;
    *margin-right: 25.53464266230224%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright2 {
    margin-right: 19.65811965811966%;
    *margin-right: 19.551736679396257%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright2:last-child {
    margin-right: 17.094017094017094%;
    *margin-right: 16.98763411529369%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright1 {
    margin-right: 11.11111111111111%;
    *margin-right: 11.004728132387708%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offsetright1:last-child {
    margin-right: 8.547008547008547%;
    *margin-right: 8.440625568285142%;
  }
```