# Centering right .span9 content in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap setup is very simple and quite similar to this [example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html). I've a sidebar of the left and a content on the right. The simple task i'm tring to accomplish is centering the right side of the page.

More in general i'd like to center any div placed inside `div.span9`. I've used `.span4 .offset4` but it doesn't work:

```
<!--End of sidebar -->
<!-- Right side -->
<div class="span9">
    <!-- Right side-->
    <div class="form-container span4 offset4">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <!-- ... -->
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/span-->
```

Here you can see the complete code and a [live example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PdQc/2/). Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Bold text really doesn't help with readability. I'd refrain from using it.

Comment: @Blender so sorry, thans for your edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** : Bootstrap supports fluid offsets since 2.1.0 (or around that). See the [Fluid Offseting doc](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)

---

There is no offset in the fluid grid. Check this one : [Offset Margin-Left Percentages for Fluid Row in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11383774/1478467)

And secondly, if you put some content in the `.span4` that overflows, the centering will only be applied to the `.span4` container. You should fix the content width too (i.e. `.control-group` and `.control`).

If you prefer the easy way, you can keep the grid static (non-fluid) and use `.offsetX` classes or `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`.

Comment: Bootstrap now supports offsets in fluid grids.  See [Fluid offsetting](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)